# Normalizer vs normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group, and $U \leq G$ a subgroup of $G$.

I am trying to understand the differences between the normalizer of a subgroup, which is defined as $\text{N}_G(U) := \{g \in G: gUg^{-1} = U\}$, and a *normal subgroup*.

Since normal subgroups can be defined in many ways, I'll go with this definition for now:
$$\text{A subgroup U is normal in G iff the following holds}: \forall g \in G: gUg^{-1} = U.$$

To my understanding, *normalizer* is a weaker definition than *normal subgroup*, since in a normal subgroup, the whole subgroup is invariant under conjugation with all other elements of the group; but for elements to be in a normalizer, it just means that the subgroup is invariant under the conjugation of *these particular elements*.

Is that correct?

Comment: $U$ is normal iff $N_G(U)=G$: not sure whether this can be interpreted as you say.

Comment: The normalizer of $U$ in $G$ is the largest subgroup of $G$ that contains $U$ in which $U$ is a normal subgroup. I.e., largest $H$ such that $U\leq H\leq G$ with $U\triangleleft H$.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of normaliser subgroup can’t really be stronger or weaker than that of a normal subgroup, in my opinion, since they’re trying to talk about different things.

Note that a normaliser subgroup need not be normal in $G$. What $N_G(U)$ is, is *the largest subgroup $V$ of $G$ with $U$ a normal subgroup of $V$*. That’s pretty immediate from the definition.

> for elements to be in a normaliser, it just means that the subgroup is invariant under conjugation by these particular elements.

Yes, but your comparison with normal subgroups doesn’t quite make sense. At least, I can’t see a coherent point that you’re trying to make. Again, these definitions are going after different concepts. To say a subgroup is normal is to describe a property of that subgroup, but a normaliser subgroup is a subgroup explicitly constructed to have a particular property. It’s like the difference between describing a real number as nonnegative and taking its absolute value. The purpose of the normaliser is to make $U$ normal, in an optimal way.

It may help to observe that the normaliser $N_G(U)$ is equal to all of $G$ iff. $U$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

You can formally convey the concept of being a condition $P$ *weaker* than another condition $Q$ (in some "universe" $\mathcal U$), by showing that the set $\mathcal Q:=\{x\in \mathcal U\mid Q(x)\}$ is *included* in the set $\mathcal P:=\{x\in \mathcal U\mid P(x)\}$. Now, by definition of normalizer, $U$ is a subset (subgroup) of $N_G(U)$ *irrespective* of being $U$ normal in $G$. This alone should prevent to look for any "direct comparison" between the two concepts, one of which is a group built up from $U$ as such (namely $N_G(U)$), whereas the other one is a *possible property* of $U$ (being normal).

If you want a ($U$-based) defining property of another set to be *stronger* than the one defining $N_G(U)$, you should look at the *centralizer* of $U$ in $G$, usually denoted with $C_G(U)$. For the definition and the mutual relation with $N_G(U)$, look at, *e.g.*, [this wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer).